# is there a way to get the sign-in information of a user (blocked or not) using powershell (exchange online) without having to connect to msol service

Tags: powershell, office365, exchange-server

We are trying to automate mailbox full access permission (when an employee exits company his manager will get access to his mailbox for 30 days) so the first check the Bot does is to check for the sign-in status and then it proceeds forward to delegation (assigning fullaccess). We have a problem connecting to msol-service using bot. However, Bot is able to connect to exchange online using powershell. So we are thinking if there is a way to get the sign-in info for an user using exchange online only. Any way if we can get to add the user to a DL or a DDL once the sign-in status is blocked (creating a task to run in the background) as the sole purpose of this is to automate without having to do it manually. Appreciate any suggestion, many thanks!

Connect-MsolService -Credential $UserCredential
Connect-AzureAD -Credential $UserCredential
Connect-ExchangeOnline –Credential $UserCredential
Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName " " | select BlockCredential | Export-CSV 'c:\abc\xyz.csv'  -NoTypeInformation

the Uipath is not able to connect to msolservice (it connects to exchange online otherwise). Any changes in the command without having to include msolservice?

Comment: No.  Port Forwarding is used.  Corporate Networks forward all email port numbers to a Proxy Server that check credentials.  From inside the network you cannot use gmail because the gmail port number is same outlook and will get forwarded to the proxy server.

Comment: We have linux machines that are not on the Windows Network and do not have windows credentials.  We have a bridge setup that the linux machines can send SMTP email on port 25 without credentials and then the bridge forwards the email to the Outlook email server which then sends the emails.